# Python: Parameters for Looping with Remote Variables

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to create a loop that cycles through two lists (one local in the module, another remote in a different module that I'm using as a temporary storage for access by other modules in the package). I can boil this down into a small function that loops through everything **except** for the remote variable store that is held in **remote.asset** in the code below.

```
import remote

value_name = ['asset', 'liability']
value = {'asset':1.1, 'liability':2.2}

def sanity_check():
    for i in range(len(value_name)):
        if value_name[i] == 'asset':
            remote.asset = value['{}'.format(value_name[i])]
            local_display = '{:,.2f}'.format(value['{}'.format(value_name[i])])
            remote_display = '{:,.2f}'.format(remote.asset)
            print('local - ' + str(local_display) + '    remote - ' + str(remote_display))
        if value_name[i] == 'liability':
            remote.liability = value['{}'.format(value_name[i])]
            local_display = '{:,.2f}'.format(value['{}'.format(value_name[i])])
            remote_display = '{:,.2f}'.format(remote.liability)
            print('local - ' + str(local_display) + '    remote - ' + str(remote_display))

sanity_check()
```

The remote store just holds values, like this:

```
global asset 
asset = 0.0
global liability
liability = 0.0
```

To get a value from the remote store, I have to use its name, like this:

```
remote_display = '{:,.2f}'.format(remote.asset)
```

I would prefer to use a reference to the variable name like I do with the local variable

```
local_display = '{:,.2f}'.format(value['{}'.format(value_name[i])])
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can make the name of the remote variable (*the hashed portion below*) be a variable:

```
remote_display = '{:,.2f}'.format(remote.#####)
```

Is there a way to call the remote part (the ".asset" portion) as a variable so that I can loop through one chunk of code instead of breaking out a chunk for every possible entry in my value_name list?

Thanks for looking; I have tried numerous approaches, but can't figure out how to call this one.

---

SOLVED: implementing Charles Duffy's answer resulted in the following code:

```
import remote

value_name = ['asset', 'liability']
value = {'asset':1.1, 'liability':2.2}

def sanity_check():
    for i in range(len(value_name)):
        setattr(remote, value_name[i], value['{}'.format(value_name[i])])
        local_display = '{:,.2f}'.format(value['{}'.format(value_name[i])])
        remote_display = '{:,.2f}'.format(getattr(remote, value_name[i])) 
        print('local - ' + str(local_display) + '    remote - ' + str(remote_display))

sanity_check()
```

There will be more changes based on additional tips that he provided, but this is where I am right now. Thanks Charles.

Comment: BTW, why are you dealing with numeric indexes instead of `for value in value_names:` and just referring to `value` instead of `value_name[i]`? The `range(len(...))` bit is just making code less readable (and ever so slightly slower) for no benefit.

Comment: Similarly, if `value_names` will only contain the list of keys in your `values` (okay, not plural in the original code, but it *should* be plural -- that way you can have a singular `value` refer to just one item from it), why not just ask `values` what its keys are, and not have the separate list at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `getattr()` and `setattr()`.

That is:

```
values = {'asset': 1.1, 'liability': 2.2}

def sanity_check():
    for key in values.keys():
        # Q:Why are you bothering to print remote if you force it to match the local value?
        setattr(remote, key, values[key])  ## instead of remote.<key> = values[key]

        print('local - {:,.2f}    remote - {:,.2f}'.format(values[key],
                                                           getattr(remote, key))
```

---

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

> `getattr(object, name[, default])`
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of *object*. *name* must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`. If the named attribute does not exist, *default* is returned if provided, otherwise `AttributeError` is raised.

Comment: setattr & getattr are exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much Charles. I am now able to run this loop as a single block of code. Thanks also for all of your other comments & suggestions - I am looking at and working through them all in an iterative manner to build my Python knowledge - very helpful.